# Netbeans import doesn't work automatically

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0.1 for about 2 years. Since today I have a problem with this program.

Normally when I use a class like `ApplicationContext`, Netbeans automatically fixes the import-statement, but that doesn't work anymore. When I type the import statement by myself, Netbeans recognizes it...

Comment: What do you mean that it does not import? It is adding the import lines and showing some error, or not adding them at all?

Comment: He is not adding them at all. When I click on the red exclamation mark on the left, I don't have the option to import it...

(When I add the import line by myself it works... )

Comment: What OS are you using? Something similar happened to me before, because I was using Linux with IBus on it, and the OS shortcuts was overwritting the shortcuts of Netbeans.

Comment: Installing a new Netbeans doesn't help..

Comment: Check that you don't have any Windows key short cut with the same key combination than Netbeans import.